# Is there any better way to pass sensitive data to the program, alternative to env variables?

Tags: node.js, testing, twitter, environment-variables

I want to use npm twitter package, and it [recommends to use env variables](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter#quick-start), but *[setting it up on windows machines is horror](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=setting+up+env+variables+on+windows&hl=en&biw=1362&bih=666&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=0WU9VcapDcSisgHKs4HIAg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw)*, so I want to avoid env variables. Next try is keep variables in external json file ([like here in my repo](https://github.com/iamstarkov/fetch-twitter-account/blob/master/index.js#L5)), which is never be committed, but *it’s playing not good with CI*, because if it’s not in the repo, how can I use it and test, right?

Let me show.

**env variables (windows users’ nightmare):**

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
});
```

**untestable crap**

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var keys = require('./keys.json');
var client = new Twitter(keys);
```

with this line in `.gitignore`:

```
keys.json
```

**no winners situation; is there any better way?**

There are no winners in this situation and it makes me sad. *I want to achieve two simple goals: easy consumption and testability.* Can you help me? How do you deal with this?

**Update:** I’m talking in terms of developing opensource lib based on twitter API, not about end user product, that’s I feel unsecure about keeping tokens in repo.

**Update 2:** Windows users’ have `set` and `setx` commands. Hurray! thx to Martin Konecny for noting this.

**Solution:** while there is no crap in setting up env variables in windows, *it’s better to let code consumer to choose how to pass data to his end-product (which is using my lib). So we end up with situation, which has no "data-passing" problem.* And because of it it’s testable, because I can use env variables in my tests to test it in Travis CI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just let your user choose what's best for him. implement (or use library as there are such libraries for most languages) something that will let you pass and shadow properties in many different formats: api, file, envs, command line.
then:

- in your local test you can simply use api as part of test configuration
- in your integration tests you can put json file (ignored by git)
- on travis you can use command line parameters or environment properties
- on production you will use environment properties or remote server with configuration

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this is an open-source project, you will most likely not be able to include your Twitter API keys inside the project itself. I see two potential solutions:

1. Require the users to register for their own Twitter API
   credentials, and add these to your project's config file before
   running the project and its tests.
2. If you are trying to use
   something like Travis CI to auto-test any new commits, you may need to [mock your requests](https://github.com/pgte/nock) instead.

Option #2 may not be ideal since it doesn't take into account any future API changes from Twitter, however it allows you to test breakage of any commits assuming the API does remain stable.

Comment: "Require the users to register for their own Twitter API credentials" — it’s okay

Comment: the real question is about how pass it’s to program and not to use env variables and not to use config files.

Comment: Assuming they are running the tests from the windows terminal, what's to stop them from doing `set TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=xxx` ?

Comment: I used to think, that windows users have to use these [ugly interfaces](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=setting+up+env+variables+on+windows&hl=en&biw=1362&bih=666&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=KWw9VcDZOsv7ywOOx4CIDQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAw).

Comment: whoa! windows users have built-in `set` and even permanent `setx` variables! thank you a lot